# How to set a Checkbox checked property to true

Tags: c#, checkbox

I want to set the default property of a checkbox to true

Answer (score 11):

I suppose you only mean that on opening a form, one or more check boxes are   checked .

Simply write in the `Form_Load` method

```
private void Form_Loaded (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    CheckBox1.IsChecked = true;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

chkEntregue.CheckState = CheckState.Checked;

Answer (score 3):

Set the Checked property to True in the Properties window of Visual Studio at design time.

Answer (score 3):

To set CheckBox:

```
 CheckBoxName.SetCurrentValue(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, true);
```

To unset CheckBox:

```
 CheckBoxName.SetCurrentValue(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, false);
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified which platform, so I'll answer this for WPF, in which it's definitely possible.

You can use the [OverrideMetadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597491.aspx) method on CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty to provide a default value of "true" for all CheckBoxes. Add this code to your App class (in App.xaml.cs):

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CheckBox),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(true));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For a given checkbox?  Edit the form in the forms designer, and change the `Checked` property to true.

For all checkboxes in the environment, without changing each individually?  Can't be done.  Though I suppose if you got really ambitious, you could write a post-compiler or some such.